# Selecting column / SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Tags: jquery, primefaces

I'm working on a project with PrimeFaces template.
In p:datatable, i want to select a column's content.
I tried Jquery to do this

```
$()(function(){
        $(document).on('click','td[role=gridcell]',function(){ this.select(); });
    });
```

but got this SyntaxError: function statement requires a name.
Columns like this;

```
<p:column sortBy="#{byn.referans}" filterBy="#{byn.referans}"
                    filterMatchMode="contains" filterEvent="enter" >
                    <f:facet name="header">#{msg['beyanname.tablecolumn.referans']}</f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{byn.referans}" />
                </p:column>
```

Comment: If using `this` in a jQuery context it should be `$(this)`

Comment: The error comes from `$()(function(){` which should be just `$(function(){`. Typo !

Comment: Thanks. I did correction what you said but error continues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give your p:dataTable / editable="false" and
change h:outputText to h:inputText. Your column should be like this.

```
<h:inputText value="#{byn.referans}" readonly="true" styleClass="selectable-column"/>
```

Then in your stylesheet, make the column's cell look like a normal cell.

```
.selectable-column {width: 100%; background-color: transparent; border: none;}
```